# timer as part of a struct

Tags: c#

I have the following struct

```
private struct sData{
    public int volume;      
    public System.Timers.Timer aliveTimer;
    public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this = " + volume);// I cannot access volume here
    }
}
```

and when the time elapsed i want to change volume value and i can't access it in OnTimedEvent
I use this code to start the struct and the timer:

```
sData ret = new sData();
ret.volume = rand.Next(1, 10) * 100;    
ret.aliveTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
ret.aliveTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(sData.OnTimedEvent);
ret.aliveTimer.Start();
```

what should I do?

Comment: What is the error you get? Furthermore why use struct and not a class?

Comment: Change it to be a `class`? Mutable `struct`s are rarely a good idea anyway. Why did you create it as a `struct`?

Comment: Events on a `struct` are usually a bad move. Why is this a `struct`? If you can't answer **clearly** why it is a `struct`, then it almost certainly shouldn't be one. And a *mutable* `struct` with a public field is just *begging* for problems.

Comment: Now... what do you mean by "I cannot access volume here"?

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TimerTester.Form1.sData.volume' D:\webwork\TimerTester\TimerTester\TimerTester\Form1.cs 29 47 TimerTester

Comment: @adam the `struct sData` code you have posted compiles fine. Did you change the code when posting it? Note: the fact that it compiles **does not** mean it is sensible code ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite it to:

```
private class Data{
    public int Volume {get; set; }      
    private System.Timers.Timer _aliveTimer;

    public Data() 
    {   
        _aliveTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    }

    public void Start() 
    {
        _aliveTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this = " + volume);
    }
}

Data ret = new Data();
ret.Volume = rand.Next(1, 10) * 100;    
ret.Start();
```

Using a class is always a better idea than a struct. Furthurmore Data contains a timer and yet you are setting the OnTimedEvent handler (which is defined in Data) from another component. Bit unlogical.

Comment: minor tweak - I'd make `Volume` an auto-prop; public fields are never a good idea. It is not clear how `_aliveTimer` will ever get a non-null value here, or how it will get cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

k; I understand the error message now. In your example code, you have:

```
ret.aliveTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(sData.OnTimedEvent);
```

which suggests that in your *real* code, `OnTimedEvent` is `static` - which explains why you are getting the message (comments):

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TimerTester.Form1.sData.volume

So; the initial problem is that `OnTimedEvent` should not be `static`. This in turn means that the event subscription would be:

```
ret.aliveTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ret.OnTimedEvent);
```

or simply:

```
ret.aliveTimer.Elapsed += ret.OnTimedEvent;
```

However! Event subscriptions on structs are... risky. The copy semantics of structs makes it virtually impossible to use them correctly as either event-sources or subscribers. `sData` is *clearly* not a "value", so it simply shouldn't be a `struct`: it should be a `class`. If you are ever in doubt, `class` covers the 99.99% of scenarios. `struct` is **very** rare, and even rarer when used *correctly* rather than someone who thinks that `struct` means "like a `class` but cheaper" (this is not what it means).

I would also change many features of `sData` (including the name, the use of public fields, exposed implementation details, etc) - but that is secondary to the two big problems:

- confusion over the usage of `struct`
- confusion over the usage of `static`